# Azure AD b2c Custom policy: Change User Profile picture

Tags: azure, image, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to change or upload a user profile while signup or profile update in azure active directory b2c using custom policy. I found a "thumbnailPhoto" property having datatype Edm.Stream by using this I am trying to create a custom ClaimType like this. but it's not working please help in changing user profile through custom policy

```
 <ClaimType Id="thumbnailPhoto">
        <DisplayName>ProfilePicture</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stream</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Upload profile picture</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this thread could be useful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64593/how-can-i-implement-azure-b2c-profile-including-pr.html

Comment: Thank you for your response @Thomas yesterday I go through this thread but not clearly get idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks and Azure B2C support below predefined data types.

Reference:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#datatype

> stream

When you upload policy, you will get error - The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06:DataType' element is invalid - **The value 'stream' is invalid according to its datatype** 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06:DataType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

> Proposed Solution:-

You need to use custom development using HTML or B2C with graph api.You can try to use the [profilePhoto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profilephoto?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource type which lets you get/update a photo.
This may work:

GET [https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version](https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/%7Buser_id%7D/thumbnailPhoto?api-version)

PATCH [https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version](https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/%7Buser_id%7D?api-version)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, I am working on graph API after posting this question. but I am still having some issues using graph api like some posts or articles write beta instead of myorganization do I need to replace this with something or do I need to replace tenant Id. and where i can found api-version? and can i use this api first to hint through postman for testing. sorry for if it feel annoying i am working on this from last 3 days please help.

Comment: Thanks and please follow the samples -https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser